# Unable to get javascript value from label

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm a newbie in programming thus do pardon me.

I have a .js game that outputs a variable called "score".

I require the variable to be able to be displayed on my asp label and after which grabbing its value for database storage onClick()

Currently what I have been able to do were:

@ .js:

```
    document.getElementById('score').value = score;
```

@ .aspx:

```
    <asp:Label runat="server"  ID="score"></asp:Label>
```

The score is reflected on this label right now. However, I need to do a additional function which is to obtain the value of 'score' from the label and use it as a String in C#

Comment: Side note: asp-classic is unlikely the tag you want... at least your code is in ASP.Net... re-tagged.

Answer (score 3):

Use ClientID of server control as id score would have changed in the generated html by asp.

**Change**

```
document.getElementById('score').value = score;
```

**To**

```
document.getElementById('<%= score.ClientID %>').value = score;
```

Comment: Hi Adil, I have used your above codes. However, when i call label.Text in my C# code, it shows null

Comment: Label text is not posted back you can use hidden field to store the value and access it in code behind. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.aspx

Comment: This error occurred when I use the hiddenfield Error 10 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You have to use Value instead of Text

Comment: .js:  document.getElementById('<%= score.ClientID %>').value = score;

Comment: .asp: <asp:HiddenField ID="score" runat="server" />

Comment: .cs:String s1 = score1.Value;

Comment: If you access the value of hidden field before postback then you will not get the value assigned by javascript. Put this String s1 = score1.Value; in the button click event

Comment: It's in a button click event already. But still no results. I'm guessing its javascript --> hiddenfield that has a prob. Oh by the way thanks so much for your time and effort in helping me. much appreciated! :)

Comment: Give it one more try, in button add OnClientClick="SomeJSFun();" and in script section add function SomeJSFun(){ document.getElementById('<%= score.ClientID %>').value = "123"} and put debugger in .cs button click event

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try the below suggession.

### in .js

```
document.getElementById('<%= lblScore.ClientID %>').innerHTML = 'Test Value';
document.getElementById('<%= hdnScore.ClientID %>').value = 'Test Value';
```

### in .aspx

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblScore"></asp:Label>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnScore" runat="server" />
```

### onclick event

```
var score = hdnScore.Value;
```

Hope this will help you to fix the issue.